# Python, how to POST statuses/update_with_media to Twitter?

Tags: python, twitter

I am able to successfully post status updates (tweet) in Python with that:

```
import urllib
import oauth2 as oauth

token = oauth.Token(access_token,access_token_secret)
consumer = oauth.Consumer(consumer_key,consumer_secret)

client = oauth.Client(consumer,token)

data = {'status': 'hello world'}
request_uri = 'https://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/update.json'

resp, content = client.request(request_uri, 'POST', urllib.urlencode(data))
```

Now I would like to know what I need to change to be able to post a picture with update_with_media?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

At last i got it working and wanted to let know for people who is struggling with this how i finally easily did it with the nice Twython library, it abstract the functions nicely:

```
from twython import Twython

twitter = Twython(
    twitter_token = 'consumer_key',
    twitter_secret = 'consumer_secret',
    oauth_token = 'access_token',
    oauth_token_secret = 'access_token_secret'
)

twitter.updateStatusWithMedia('/home/blah/projects/pathexample/static/example.png', status='hello!')
```

Comment: looks like this is no longer the interface. now it's called update_status_with_media() and works somehow different.

Answer (score 1):

Something along these lines perhaps ?

```
data = {'status': 'hello world'
      , 'media': ['image.jpg']
      }
request_uri = 'https://upload.twitter.com/1/statuses/update_with_media.json'

resp, content = client.request(request_uri, 'POST', urllib.urlencode(data))
```

This was just quickly scraped together by checking out [Working with statuses/update_with_media](https://dev.twitter.com/discussions/1059?page=4) and [POST statuses/update_with_media](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1/post/statuses/update_with_media) and may not be correct.

Comment: I tried that but it fails with "Error creating status." Which does not help a lot :(

Comment: I get a status 403, the Twitter doc says: The request is understood, but it has been refused. An accompanying error message will explain why. This code is used when requests are being denied due to update limits.