# python-twitter program only runs in shell

Tags: python, twitter, python-twitter

I am new to the Twitter API and python-twitter. I am trying to run the simple program below:

```
import twitter
api = twitter.Api()
user = 'GoldmanSachs'
statuses = api.GetUserTimeline(screen_name=user)
for s in statuses:
    print s
```

When I run the program in the Python Shell I get the expected output below.

> {"created_at": "Mon Jan 28 22:21:14 +0000 2013", "favorited": false,
>   "id": 296020134164836353, "retweet_count": 2, "retweeted": false,
>   "source": "web", "text": "ICYMI: WSJ's Davos Live Blog spoke to FX de
>   Mallmann about European corporations raising funds in the bond market.
>   http://t.co/hCLGBOOy", ....}

However, when I try to save the program and then run it I get an AttributeError:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "\twitter.py", line 1, in <module>
    import twitter
  File "\twitter.py", line 6, in <module>
    api = twitter.Api()
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'Api'
```

Any thoughts on why this is happening would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: see this maybe can serve you

[Python, how to POST statuses/update_with_media to Twitter?][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10719714/python-how-to-post-statuses-update-with-media-to-twitter/11442747#11442747

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Most likely you named your program `twitter.py` and it's shadowing `python-twitter`. Rename your script.

Comment: I changed the name of the program and I get the same error :(

Comment: anything else named twitter?

Comment: Found it! You were right there was another twitter.py program out there. I feel like such a noob.